# F# upcasting TextBlock to UIElement

Tags: .net, f#, uielement

What is wrong with:

```
let (x:UIElement) = upcast new TextBlock()
```

The error is: The type 'System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize' is required here and is unavailable. You must add a reference to assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0....'

`TextBlock` *is* a subtype of `UIElement`...

Note that doing what the error message says does solve the issue, but why is that necessary to do something as basic as upcasting?

Comment: TextBlock inherits from FrameworkElement which implements ISupportInitialize so I guess all types in the inheritance chain must be available.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738349/why-must-i-chain-reference-assemblies

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As *lasseespeholt* mentioned in his (now deleted?) answer, there is nothing wrong with your code and you just need to add the reference to `System.dll` as the error message suggests.

**But what is going on?**
You are getting the error message on that particular line, because it is the first place where the compiler encounters some type from the `System.dll` library (an interface `ISupportInitialize`, which is implemented by `TextBlock`) and realizes that it needs the reference to the library in order to understand the type.

Another way to get the same error message is to write this:

```
let x = new TextBlock() 
x.  // If you get IntelliSense here, you'll see just '<Note>' 
    // with the same error message as the one you're getting
```

In this case, the IntelliSense needs to look at the type (so that it can populate member completion).

Comment: TextBlock itself is not in System.dll, but rather *inherits an interface* that is in System.dll.

Comment: @Mauricio: That's what I meant, but my description wasn't very clear - I added a not explaiining that it is because of the interface. Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233220.aspx):

"In many object-oriented languages, upcasting is implicit; in F#, the rules are slightly different. Upcasting is applied automatically when you pass arguments to methods on an object type. However, for let-bound functions in a module, upcasting is not automatic, unless the parameter type is declared as a flexible type. For more information, see [Flexible Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233198.aspx) (F#)."

If you'd use the following syntax:

```
let (x:#UIElement) = new TextBlock()
```

your code would use a flexible type (indicated by the `#`) and it would compile. However, now you would get a warning:

"This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by its type annotations. The type variable implied by the use of a '#', '_' or other type annotation at or near 'c:\path\Program.fs' has been constrained to be type 'TextBlock'."

Comment: this answers the question "why upcast?" not "why is the reference needed?" which is what the OP is asking.