# why test assembly need to reference the driver assembly again?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I have a VS project A  and test project for A called TA

so A (unsigned ) referenced some signed assembly moduleB, in my understanding since TA is already reference A's assembly, I don't need to explicitly reference moduleB. but if I don't do that the compiler complains:

> Error 5   The type 'module B' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'module B,
>   Version=9, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=x'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will only get these at compile time if you're using an object that gets methods/properties/members etc from assembly B

This is because `.NET cannot rely on assembly A to ensure it will be able to obtain proper symbol and meta data information`.

[Answer Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738349/why-must-i-chain-reference-assemblies?rq=1)

Comment: @zinking But members of A might be accessing B, In that case compiler will expect TA to have reference to B as well.\

Comment: I haven't used any method that relates with B, but A do have some method taht return a class that is defined in B which I haven't used at all. is that to say even under this case, I still have to import the B assembly because A exposed public interfaces that dependent on B ?

Comment: that is the case, understood.